# Keyboard shortcut for a specific font

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

In Microsoft Powerpoint, is there a way to create a shortcut that changes the selected text to a specific font?

Right now, when I click "Ctrl+T", I get to the Font dialog, but it does not automatically select my desired font - I need to type the font-name each time.

One option that I thought of was to create a VBA macro. But there are two problems: (1) I do not know how to change the font from within the macro, (2) I do not know how to save the macro to Powerpoint in general (Powerpoint only lets me save to macro to a specific presentation, so it will not be available in other presentations).

Answer (score 2):

PowerPoint doesn't let us assign keystrokes to macros the ways some of the other Office programs do, unfortunately. If you use Windows PPT, there's a third-party add-in that enables you to do this: http://officeoneonline.com/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html

[Disclaimer: Not my product, I have no financial interest in it whatever, but the author is an acquaintance of mine. Honest, good guy.]

You can make a macro available to all open presentations by storing it in a PPTM that you keep open whenever you're working with PowerPoint, but it would take as many keystrokes to invoke the macro as it would to change the font normally, so that's kind of a non-starter.

You can also create your macro and save it as an add-in (PPAM) file. Once you load that, it will continue to load when PPT starts and will be available to all open presentations, but you need to also create a user interface ... ribbon buttons, for example .. to trigger the macro.  That ups the complexity of the game.

The actual code is simple enough:

```
Sub MakeItArial()

' Make sure that some text is selected
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionText Then
    ' Set the font name
    ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
End If

End Sub
```

You might need to add more code to set the font when a shape rather than text is selected, and to do nothing if there are no open presentations and so forth.